# Schema direction "perpendicular to paper"

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I have a schema that represents the sectional view of a translation system. I want to express the idea that an object is moving in the direction perpendicular the the schema that I drawn.

So far I came to: **"the object’s movement direction is through the paper"**

What would be a more correct way to express this ?

Comment: The object's movement is perpendicular to the plane of the page.  But wouldn't you normally reference the item represented in the schema rather than the schema as drawn?

Comment: @TRomano Exactly what I was looking for, you should make that an answer. 

I don't clearly understand your remark, is "the schema that I drawn" that is bothering you ? I drawn both the schema and the object (the object is part of the schema). Is it not a correct way to say it ?

Comment: I was asking, wouldn't you normally say the object's movement is perpendicular to *something represented in the drawing* rather than perpendicular to the page that contains the drawing?

Comment: Normally yes, but it's not that easy in this case... Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the object’s movement direction is through the paper

This can catch someone off guard, as illustrations on paper are normally "self-contained" - meaning anything having to do with the illustration is expected to be in the illustration - unless clearly labeled or additionally communicated otherwise.

So saying "through the paper" will sound weird unless you say this:

> the object's movement *would be* through the paper.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'll use the option that TRomano gave in his comment, it fits better my case.